# Unknown error in C# when writing an If statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am trying to write an If statement in C# where the user is asked to input the age, the program prints the age and if the user is eligible to cast the vote, where the age limit is 18.

When running the code in Visual Studio there are no errors, but on the platform where I am doing the exercise I have an error printed:

> Incorrect output: your program printed "18", but should have printed "18"

It will be much appreciated if you could only point out the mistake (if any).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int age;
    Console.Write("Please input your age: ");
    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write(age);
    Console.Write("\n");

    if (age < 18)
    {
        Console.Write("You cannot cast your vote!");
    }
    else
        Console.Write("You can cast your vote!");
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like "the platform where you are doing the exercise" is the key piece of information here. It's possible that they're expecting `\r\n` instead of `\n` - is there any reason you're writing the newline explicitly instead of just using `Console.WriteLine` to start with?

Comment: Take a look at the brackets after the else. Didn't you mean to encapsulate the console.write statement?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Jon, I replaced `\n` with `Console.WriteLine` and looks better.

Comment: @YigalB, thank you, that was one of the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is with your code, it might be with the platform evaluating the answer.

That said, a few pointers:

The brackets after the else *can be* removed or the code needs to be moved between the brackets.

These 2 lines:

```
Console.Write(age);
Console.Write("\n");
```

can be changed to:

```
Console.WriteLine(age);
```

alternatively the line:

```
Console.Write("\n");
```

can be:

```
Console.Write("\r\n");
```

The error might be down to the platform that is evaluating the answer. (online ?)
I don't know how exactly those platforms work, but if you take the code below:

```
 TextReader tr = Console.In;
 char[] buffer = new char[4];
 tr.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
 string consoleOutput = new string(buffer);
 if (consoleOutput != 18.ToString())
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"Expected 18, you entered {consoleOutput}");
 }
```

When entering 18 the result comes back as `18/r/n` as shown in this image:

[image: console_output]

and this will also give you the output *Expected 18, you entered 18*